# Python regex for MD5 hash

Tags: python, regex, md5

I've come up with:

```
re.findall("([a-fA-F\d]*)", data)
```

but it's not very fool proof, is there a better way to grab all MD5-hash codes?

Comment: What sort of fools are you proofing against?

Comment: Add `r` before `"`: c = r"[a-fA-F\d]"; re.findall(r"(?<!%s)(?:%s){32}(?!%s)" % (c,)*3, data)

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'll add the length thing, that was the main thing I had a problem with.  Will use the 'r' thing in future too, thanks for the tip!

Comment: `(c,)*3` should be replaced by `(c,c,c)` in my comment.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Well, since md5 is just a string of 32 hex digits, about all you could add to your expression is a check for "32 digits", perhaps something like this?

```
re.findall(r"([a-fA-F\d]{32})", data)
```

Comment: Isn't MD5 all lowercase? This would be much better `[0-9a-f]{32}`

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal#Using_0.E2.80.939_and_A.E2.80.93F) says: *There is no universal convention to use lowercase or uppercase for the letter digits, and each is prevalent or preferred in particular environments by community standards or convention.*
You should cover all cases to be on the safe side.

Comment: While this do match a md5 hash, it also matches a sha1 or sha2 hash, or for that matter, any hexadecimal string larger than 32. You should refine your regex by requiring the data to have a start and an end: `^[a-fA-F\d]{32}$`

Comment: @TomMaier then you can also specify `re.compile(r'[0-9a-f]{32}', re.IGNORECASE)` if you want to keep the regex cleaner

Answer (score 12):

When using regular expressions in Python, you should almost always use the raw string syntax `r"..."`:

```
re.findall(r"([a-fA-F\d]{32})", data)
```

This will ensure that the backslash in the string is not interpreted by the normal Python escaping, but is instead passed through to the `re.findall` function so it can see the `\d` verbatim. In this case you are lucky that `\d` is not interpreted by the Python escaping, but something like `\b` (which has completely different meanings in Python escaping and in regular expressions) would be.

See the [`re` module documentation](http://python.org/doc/2.5/lib/module-re.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Greg - I edited my answer to include the "r", best not to introduce subtle bugs!

Answer (score 10):

Here's a better way to do it than some of the other solutions:

```
re.findall(r'(?i)(?<![a-z0-9])[a-f0-9]{32}(?![a-z0-9])', data)
```

This ensures that the match must be a string of 32 hexadecimal digit characters, *but which is not contained within a larger string of other alphanumeric characters.* With all the other solutions, if there is a string of 37 contiguous hexadecimals the pattern would match the first 32 and call it a match, or if there is a string of 64 hexadecimals it would split it in half and match each half as an independent match. Excluding these is accomplished via the lookahead and lookbehind assertions, which are non-capturing and will not affect the contents of the match.

Note also the (?i) flag which will makes the pattern case-insensitive which saves a little bit of typing, and that wrapping the entire pattern in parentheses is superfluous.

Comment: Why not just add ^ and $ line anchors instead of using lookahead and lookbehind?

Comment: I assumed he was searching for md5s within a larger amount of text. If you're checking whether a single string entirely contains an md5, anchors would be the better way of doing that.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a fairly pedantic expression:

```
r"\b([a-f\d]{32}|[A-F\d]{32})\b"
```

- string must be exactly 32 characters long,
- string must be between a word boundary (newline, space, etc),
- alpha must all be lowercase a-f ***OR*** all uppercase A-F, but not mixed.

But if that just a'int good enough fr'yer, because you know there is only a 1 in 3402823 chance of getting an all-numeric MD5 checksum, and a 42 trillion to one chance of an all-alphanumeric MD5 checksum, then you know we should probably say FU to those valid sums and also not accept anything that isn't alphanumeric:

```
r"\b(?!^[\d]*$)(?!^[a-fA-F]*$)([a-f\d]{32}|[A-F\d]{32})\b"

00000000000000000000000000000000 # not MD5
01110101001110011101011010101001 # not MD5
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff # not MD5
A32efC32c79823a2123AA8cbDDd3231c # not MD5
affa687a87f8abe90d9b9eba09bdbacb # is MD5
C787AFE9D9E86A6A6C78ACE99CA778EE # is MD5
please like and subscribe to my  # not MD5
```

yes i've been terribly bored at work.

Comment: This only works if you're scanning individual lines. TBH `r"\b[a-f\d]{32}\b|\b[A-F\d]{32}\b"` is better.

Comment: Nice :)

I guess it all depends on the use case. Do you want to check if a string is MD5-like, or do you want to generate MD5-like strings from a larger string? :P

Comment: Agreed. I imagine a file full of MD5s that are comma-delimited not newline-delimited.

Comment: I have edited my example to include word delimiters, because you are clearly right Adam :)

Answer (score 3):

### MD5 Python Regex With Examples

Since an MD5 is composed of exactly 32 Hexadecimal Characters, and sometimes the hash is presented using lowercase letters, one should account for them as well.

---

The below example was tested against four different strings:

- A valid lowecase MD5 hash
- A valid uppercase MD5 hash
- A string of 64 Hexadecimal characters (to ensure a split & match wouldn't occur)
- A string of 37 Hexadecimal characters (to ensure the leading 32 characters wouldn't match)

> 900e3f2dd4efc9892793222d7a1cee4a
>
> AC905DD4AB2038E5F7EABEAE792AC41B
>
> 900e3f2dd4efc9892793222d7a1cee4a900e3f2dd4efc9892793222d7a1cee4a
>
> 900e3f2dd4efc9892793222d7a1cee4a4a4a4

---

```
    validHash = re.finditer(r'(?=(\b[A-Fa-f0-9]{32}\b))', datahere)

    result = [match.group(1) for match in validHash]

    if result: 

        print "Valid MD5"

    else:

        print "NOT a Valid MD5"
```

---

Answer (score 2):

How about "([a-fA-F\d]{32})" which requires it to be 32 characters long?